# C UINT16 How to get it right?

Tags: c, int, uint16

I'm new on C programming and I'm testing some code where I receive and process an UDP packet formatted as follow:

```
UINT16 port1
UINT16 port2
```

The corresponding values on this test are:

```
6005
5555
```

If I print the whole packet buffer I get something like this:

`u^W³^U><9e>^D`

So I thought that I would just have to break it and process as an `unsigned int` of 16 bytes. So I've tried something like this:

```
int l = 0;
unsigned int *primaryPort = *(unsigned int) &buffer[l]; 
AddToLog(logInfo, "PrimaryPort: %u\n", primaryPort);
l += sizeof(primaryPort);
unsigned int *secondaryPort = *(unsigned int) &buffer[l]; 
AddToLog(logInfo, "SecondaryPort: %u\n", secondaryPort);
l += sizeof(secondaryPort);
```

But I get wrong numbers with 8 digits.

I even tried another approach like follow, but also get the wrong number as well.

```
int l = 0;
unsigned char primaryPort[16]; 
snprintf(primaryPort, sizeof(primaryPort), "%u", &buffer[l]);
AddToLog(logInfo, "PrimaryPort: %d\n", primaryPort);
l += sizeof(primaryPort);
unsigned char secondaryPort[16]; 
snprintf(secondaryPort, sizeof(secondaryPort), "%u", &buffer[l]);
AddToLog(logInfo, "SecondaryPort: %d\n", secondaryPort);
l += sizeof(secondaryPort);
```

What I'm doing wrong? Also, why I have to free on a char string variables, but I don't need to free on int variables?

Comment: If you are asking about C, why there are C++ and C# in tags?

Comment: Most likely, on your system `unsigned int` is not in fact a 16-bit integer, and `sizeof(unsigned int) != 2`. And `*(unsigned int) &buffer[l]` doesn't make any sense (and can't compile): you are casting a pointer to an integer, and then trying to dereference said integer.

Comment: "Also, why I have to free on a char string variables, but I don't need to free on int variables?" Whether or not you have to call `free` isn't a matter of what the type of the variable is.

Comment: My educated guess is, you want something like this: `unit16_t primaryPort = ntohs(*(unit16_t*)&buffer[0]); unit16_t secondaryPort = ntohs(*(unit16_t*)&buffer[2]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing to `AddToLog` and `snprintf` pointers to the integers.  So what you're seeing are the addresses of the integers, not the integers themselves.

You need to dereference your pointers -- for example, put an asterisk (*) in front of `primaryPort` in your calls to `AddToLog` in your first approach.

As @rileyberton suggests, most likely `unsigned int` is 4 bytes on your system, which is the C99 type `uint32_t`.  For a 16-bit integer, use `uint16_t`.  These are defined in `stdint.h`.  These are traditionally called "short integers" or "half integers" and require the `%hu` qualifier in `printf` or similar functions, rather than just `%u` (which stands for `unsigned int`, whose size depends on the target machine.)

Also, as @igor-tandetnik suggests, you may need to switch the byte order of the integers in your packet, if for example the packet is using network order (big-endian) format and your target machine is using little-endian format.

Answer (score 0):

unsigned int on your system is likely 4 bytes (uint32_t).  You can use unsigned int here if you mask out the values in the correct endianess, or simply use a short.

```
int l = 0;
unsigned short *primaryPort = *(unsigned short) &buffer[l]; 
AddToLog(logInfo, "PrimaryPort: %u\n", primaryPort);
l += sizeof(*primaryPort);
unsigned short *secondaryPort = *(unsigned short) &buffer[l]; 
AddToLog(logInfo, "SecondaryPort: %u\n", secondaryPort);
l += sizeof(*secondaryPort);
```

Comment: Or a.. you know.. `uint16_t`.

Answer (score 0):

You declared `primaryPort` and `secondaryPort` to be pointers to `unsigned short`.

But when you assign them values from a section of buffer, you already de-referenced the pointer.  You don't need `pointers-to-unsigned-short`.  You just need an `unsigned short`.

Change it to:

```
unsigned short primaryPort = *((unsigned short*) &buffer[l]); 

unsigned short secondaryPort = *((unsigned short *) &buffer[l]);
```

*Note the removal of a `*` in the variable declarations.*

If you're still having problems, you'll need to examine `buffer` byte-by-byte, looking for the  value you expect.   You can expect that `6005` will show up as either hex `17 75` or `75 17`, depending on your platform's [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).