# C uint16 integer or char formatted?

Tags: c, uint16

I'm new on C programming and I'm testing some code where I receive and process an UDP packet formatted as follow:

```
UINT16 port1
UINT16 port2
```

The corresponding values on this test are:

```
6005
5555
```

If I print the whole packet buffer I get something like this:

```
u^W³^U><9e>^D
```

How can I break it and get the right values? I've tried `uint16_t` and `unsigned short` and even the function `htons`, but didn't work either I just get wrong numbers, I'm trying something like this:

```
int l = 0;
unsigned short *primaryPort = *(unsigned short*) &buffer[l]; 
AddToLog(logInfo, "PrimaryPort: %u\n", primaryPort);
l += sizeof(*primaryPort);
unsigned short *secondaryPort = *(unsigned short *) &buffer[l]; 
AddToLog(logInfo, "SecondaryPort: %u\n", secondaryPort);
l += sizeof(*secondaryPort);
```

What is the right or the best way to get these values? I think these two uint16 values are not integer formatted, I think it's just an `uint16` char text on this characters `u^W³^U><9e>^D`, so perhaps I'm getting the wrong numbers because I'm processing like an integer. But I've tried everything and I just can't get the right values.

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19370213/c-uint16-how-to-get-it-right

Comment: Because It's not the same question, when I did this one I was referring to get a formatted integer, not a uint16 char, I make this question based on the last one, I couldn't add block code on the comments, and I didn't find a way to create a child question related to the previous one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I look at the buffer you receive, it indeed starts with 6005 (little Endian):

6005 is 0x1775 and the first two characters are `u` (0x75) and `Ctrl-W` (0x17). So you should get the int value by:

```
 unsigned short primaryPort = (buffer[l] & 0xff) | ((buffer[l+1] & 0xff) << 8 );
```

and the same for the secondary port.

**Edit**

It works because:

In an expression like `buffer[l] & 0xff`, `buffer[i]` is implicitly casted into an `int` (search for 'integer promotion' to learn more). Masking it with `0xff` is neccessary if `buffer` is `char *`: Then `buffer[i]` is a **signed** char and thus, if the highest bit is set, it's value is negative (e.g. `'\xff'` is -1). Masking it makes sure that we get a positive value in the range 0 - 255 instead. Last but not least, the shift operator `<< 8` shifts the byte value to the next higher byte the calculated `int`. Finally the result of the complete operation is implicitly casted to `unsigned short` which can be done safely because the calculated `int` is less or equal to 0xffff.

Comment: Please, can you point me some documentation for this or a title for me to search and study? It really worked, but I didn't quite understand your solution.

Comment: Sorry iI have no doc but I've tried to add an explanation to my answer. See my edit, I hope you come along with it.